# Share excel file on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am working on a VBA file that has a button, which should upload some data from an Excel file to a Sharepoint file. The problem is when the Sharepoint file is open it takes 2/3 times to run it to upload the information. But I want the data to be uploaded no matter if Sharepoint is open or not. This is because SharePoint is used by more than 20 people and the upload will happen a couple of times a day, so I need to be able to run this the first time, no matter if someone has opened Sharepoint.

```
Sub PopulateDataToSharePoint()
    Dim SharePointFile As String
    Dim LocalFile As String
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim SharePointWorkbook As Object
    Dim LocalWorkbook As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' File paths
    SharePointFile = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/person/Documents/test/test.xlsx"
    LocalFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\report.xlsx"
    
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    ' Open SharePoint
    Set SharePointWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(SharePointFile)
    
    ' Open local file
    Set LocalWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(LocalFile)
    
    ' Map the sheets between the local and SharePoint files
    Dim sheetMappings(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As String
    sheetMappings(1, 1) = "local1" ' Source sheet name
    sheetMappings(1, 2) = "sharepoint1" ' Destination sheet name in SharePoint
    sheetMappings(2, 1) = "local2" ' Source sheet name
    sheetMappings(2, 2) = "sharepoint2" ' Destination sheet name in SharePoint
    sheetMappings(3, 1) = "local3" ' Source sheet name
    sheetMappings(3, 2) = "sharepoint3" ' Destination sheet name in SharePoint
    
    ' Loop through the sheet mappings and copy data starting from the second row
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dim sourceSheetName As String
        Dim destinationSheetName As String
        sourceSheetName = sheetMappings(i, 1)
        destinationSheetName = sheetMappings(i, 2)
        
        ' Copy data
        LocalWorkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy _
            Destination:=SharePointWorkbook.Sheets(destinationSheetName).Range("A2")
    Next i
    
    ' Close workbooks
    SharePointWorkbook.Close True
    LocalWorkbook.Close False
    
    ExcelApp.Quit
    
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
    Set SharePointWorkbook = Nothing
    Set LocalWorkbook = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Data has been populated successfully to SharePoint.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VBA. Can you please help me with this?